# vertical scroll not not wrapping text

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

```css
.bob-vertical-scroll {
  overflow-y:auto;
  width: 16px;
  height: 130px;
}
.table-for-first-offer1 {
  width: 232px;
  height: 145px;
  float:left;
  padding-right:4px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-for-first-offer1 bob-vertical-scroll">
  <div id="bob-r3-highlights1">
    <p class="bob-prd-highlights-content">produ1</p>
    <span><hr class="bob-hr"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="bob-r3-highlights2">
    <p class="bob-prd-highlights-content">produ2</p>
    <span><hr class="bob-hr"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="bob-r3-highlights3">
    <p class="bob-prd-highlights-content">A login is a security principal, or an entity that can be authenticated by a secure system. Users need a login to connect to SQL Server. You can create a login based on a Windows principal (such as a domain user or a Windows domain group) or you can create a login that is not based on a Windows principal (such as an SQL Server login).</p>      
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a html page that has long text which should be wrapped inside the `div` but its not.

I tried by applying padding but still can't see all letters in a the word.

e.g. only "ca" is visible in word "can". Please have a look on following screenshot

How can I solve this?
I attached an image for ref:[image]

**Note:** For some reason it looks better on jsFiddle

Comment: Provide complete code with the issue. Screenshot not enough

Comment: Take a look to this: https://css-tricks.com/examples/OverflowExample/

Comment: Looks good on firefox and chrome on my computer... If you also say it looks ok when you make a jsfiddle maybe something else in your page is overriding your css... and maybe clear cache also

Comment: I can also see it working properly on chrome. Is fiddle you created showing same problem on your browser ?

Comment: The fiddle is fine and i dont know how, but the image above shows the problem i have

Comment: Long shot but try increasing the `padding-right:4px;` for the `.table-for-first-offer1` class.